# how to set and modify <tr> tag data-id Attributes based on how many tags we have

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-objects

I'm creating a 'expense tracker' for practice.

That takes a name, a date, an amount, and shows it on the table. Everything is working ok.
I add an item it will have a data-id of 0, next tr data-id of 1, next 2, and next 3 so on.

BUT

for example if I have 3 `<tr>` and I press the delete button and delete a row, and after that add another row data-id, it will be like this `tr[data-id=1],tr[data-id=2],tr[data-id=2]]`

I don't know what to do.

Please have a look at images.
[tr attr before deleting td](https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/eN82BX9azBBz.png?o=1) --- [tr attr after adding new td](https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/JzM6VOtGfYjT.png?o=1)

PS: I'm using localStorage to store table td's and get td's from it and put it back in the table. I want to remove element that have been clicked from localStorage too. I need the tr id for that.

```js
//
////// Add To The Table
//

const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", add);

function add() {
  // Select Elements
  const name = document.getElementById("name").value,
    date = document.getElementById("date").value,
    amount = document.getElementById("amount").value,
    currency = document.getElementById("selector").value;

  // Check if inputs is not empty
  if (
    name.length <= 0 ||
    date.length <= 0 ||
    amount.length <= 0 ||
    currency == "empty"
  )
    return;

  // Create Table
  const newTr = createTr(),
    tdName = createTd(),
    tdDate = createTd(),
    tdAmount = createTd(),
    tdBtn = createTd(),
    deleteBtn = createInput();

  // Set Data Attribute
  const Trs = document.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr");
  newTr.setAttribute("data-id", Trs.length);
  tdName.setAttribute("class", "data");
  tdDate.setAttribute("class", "data");
  tdAmount.setAttribute("class", "data");

  // Create Text Node
  const varName = txtNode(name),
    varDate = txtNode(date),
    varAmount = txtNode(`${amount}${currency}`);

  // Select Parent element for insert
  const table = document.querySelector("table");
  const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");

  // Creating Delete Button
  deleteBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  deleteBtn.setAttribute("value", "X");
  deleteBtn.setAttribute("class", "deleteBtn");
  deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", remover);
  // Add Elements together
  tdName.appendChild(varName);
  tdDate.appendChild(varDate);
  tdAmount.appendChild(varAmount);
  tdBtn.appendChild(deleteBtn);
  newTr.appendChild(tdName);
  newTr.appendChild(tdDate);
  newTr.appendChild(tdAmount);
  newTr.appendChild(tdBtn);
  tbody.appendChild(newTr);
  // Add to the DOM
  table.insertBefore(tbody, null);

  // Add to the Local Storage
  const storeTableTd = document.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr");

  let tableItems = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < storeTableTd.length; i++) {
    let datas = storeTableTd[i].childNodes;
    let combine = {
      id: i,
      name: datas[0].innerText,
      date: datas[1].innerText,
      amount: datas[2].innerText,
    };
    tableItems.push(combine);
  }
  localStorage.setItem(`table`, JSON.stringify(tableItems));
}
//
////// Delete All Rows
//

const clearBtn = document.getElementById("clear");
clearBtn.addEventListener("click", clear);

function clear() {
  const storeTableRow = document.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr");
  if (storeTableRow.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < storeTableRow.length; i++) {
      storeTableRow[i].remove();
    }
  }
  localStorage.clear();
}

//
//////// Restore The Table
//

function restore() {
  const storageTable = JSON.parse(localStorage.table);
  for (let i = 0; i < storageTable.length; i++) {
    // Create Elements
    const newTr = createTr(),
      createName = createTd(),
      createDate = createTd(),
      createAmount = createTd(),
      createDeleteBtn = createTd(),
      deleteBtn = createInput(),
      textNodeName = txtNode(`${storageTable[i].name}`),
      textNodeDate = txtNode(`${storageTable[i].date}`),
      textNodeAmount = txtNode(`${storageTable[i].amount}`),
      // Select Parent for Insert
      selectBody = document.querySelector("tbody");

    // Set Attributes

    newTr.setAttribute("data-id", `${storageTable[i].id}`);
    deleteBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
    deleteBtn.setAttribute("value", "X");
    deleteBtn.setAttribute("class", "deleteBtn");

    //TODO Add Delete and Create a Function withit
    createName.appendChild(textNodeName);
    createDate.appendChild(textNodeDate);
    createAmount.appendChild(textNodeAmount);
    createDeleteBtn.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    newTr.appendChild(createName);
    newTr.appendChild(createDate);
    newTr.appendChild(createAmount);
    newTr.appendChild(createDeleteBtn);
    selectBody.insertBefore(newTr, null);
  }
}

// Call Restore function

const storeTd = document.querySelectorAll("td");
if (storeTd.length == 0) {
  if (localStorage.length > 0) {
    restore();
  }
}

// Delete Button Event Listener
let selectAllBtns = document
  .querySelectorAll("input.deleteBtn")
  .forEach((item) => item.addEventListener("click", remover));

function remover(e) {
  // Remove From Local Storage
  const searchId = parseInt(e.path[2].attributes[0].value),
    storageTable = JSON.parse(localStorage.table),
    newLocalStorage = storageTable.filter((obj) => obj.id !== searchId);
  localStorage.setItem("table", JSON.stringify(newLocalStorage));

  // Remove Selected Element
  const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody"),
    elementToRemove = e.path[2];
  tbody.removeChild(elementToRemove);
}

//
////// Show Time and Date
//

// Select the Div
const getDateDiv = document.querySelector("div.date");
const getHourDiv = document.querySelector("div.hour");

function getDate() {
  // Hour
  let newDate = new Date(),
    hour = newDate.getHours(),
    amPm = hour > 12 ? "PM" : "AM",
    tweleHourFormat = hour % 12,
    minuets = newDate.getMinutes(),
    seconds = newDate.getSeconds();

  // Date
  const year = newDate.getFullYear(),
    months = newDate.getMonth() + 1,
    day = newDate.getDate();

  // Add Zero to Mineuts and Seconds
  if (minuets < 10) {
    minuets = `0${minuets}`;
  }
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }

  // Add to the Dom
  const date = `${year}/${months}/${day}`;
  const time = `${tweleHourFormat}:${minuets}:${seconds} ${amPm}`;
  getDateDiv.innerHTML = `${date}`;
  getHourDiv.innerHTML = `${time}`;
  setTimeout(getDate, 800);
}

getDate();

//
/////// Create Element Function
//

function createTd() {
  return document.createElement("td");
}

function createTr() {
  return document.createElement("tr");
}

function createInput() {
  return document.createElement("input");
}

function txtNode(node) {
  return document.createTextNode(node);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <section class="dateSection">
      <div class="date"></div>
      <div class="hour"></div>
    </section>
  </header>
  <main class="inputs">
    <section class="texts">
      <h1>Expense Tracker</h1>
      <h2>Add a New Item: </h2>
    </section>
    <section class="form">
      <div class="nameSection">
        <label id='nameLabel'>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name">
      </div>
      <div class="date__amountSection">
        <label id="dateLabel">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="date">
        <label id="amountLabel">Amount:</label>
        <input type="text" id="amount">
        <select id="selector" value="Rial">
          <option id="choose" value="empty">Choose</option>
          <option id="dollar" value="$">Dollar</option>
          <option id="rial" value="﷼">Rial</option>
          <option id="euro" value="€">Euro</option>
          <option id="pound" value="£">Pound</option>
        </select>
        <div>
    </section>
    <div class="btns">
      <input type="button" class="btns" id="btn" value="Add Expense">
      <input type="button" class="btns" id="clear" value="Clear the List">
    </div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="headName">Name</th>
          <th id="headDate">Date</th>
          <th id="headAmount">Amount</th>
          <th> </th>
        </tr>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </thead>
    </table>
    <div id="demo"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I suggest keeping track of the "last used index" in a separate variable, and the data in an array of objects separate from the DOM. Then, do all of your work (adding, updating, deleting, etc.) on the array of objects and just update the DOM from the array when you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `remover()` function to update localStorage index

replace

```
newLocalStorage = storageTable.filter((obj) => obj.id !== searchId);
```

with

```
newLocalStorage = storageTable.filter((obj) => obj.id !== searchId)
    .map((obj, index) => {
      obj.id = index;
      return obj
    });
```

and to update elements `data-id`

```
tbody.removeChild(elementToRemove);
// add this lines
document.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr").forEach((item, index) => {
  item.setAttribute("data-id", index)
})
```

demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq2kce0d/1/),